# GitHub filtering not showing approved reviews

Tags: github, pull-request

In our private GitHub repository, if I approve a PR, 90% of the time the text "Approved" does not show up in the main PR list. I say 90% because sometimes it does appear! But most of the time I have to open the pull request details to see if it was approved. This makes it difficult to manage a large list of PRs. Strangely you can see in the screenshot that "Changes requested" shows up fine.

[image: pr is approved]
[image: pr is approved2]

[image: github prs]

The filtering also seems to be broken. For example, if I search for Approved reviews, no results are returned. I don't see anything related to this in the repository settings. It seems to be a bug on the Github side as this affects both private repositories I'm actively managing the PR queues for.

[image: github filtering]

Answer (score 1):

Getting the same problem.

Workaround is with CLI gh tool
`gh pr list --json number,reviewDecision --search "state:open type:pr -review:none" | jq '.[] | select(.reviewDecision=="")'`

It looks for PRs which do not have `none` review, but whose `reviewDecision` is empty...